# Kullback–Leibler divergence between two inverse Wishart distributions

Tags: kullback-leibler, wishart-distribution

Is there a closed form formula for the KL divergence between two inverse Wishart distributions?

Comment: Eq (15) here seems to be settling this 
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.723.92&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: You could write up your findings in an answer.